# AngularJS directive not updating:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/pandaApp.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="pandaApp" ng-controller="pandaController">

<p ng-repeat="el in rainbow"><test color="{{el.color}}" ng-click="updateColor(el)"></test></p>

<li ng-repeat="el in rainbow">{{el.color}}</li>

{{dario.age}} {{dario.surname}}

</body>

</html>
```

pandaApp.js

```
var pandaApp = angular.module("pandaApp", ['ngRoute']);

pandaApp.controller('pandaController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


    $scope.rainbow = [

        {color:"red"},
        {color:"orange"},
        {color:"yellow"},
        {color:"blue"}

    ];

    $scope.updateColor = function(el) {

        el.color="changed";

    }

}]);

pandaApp.directive("test", function() {

    return {

        restrict:'E',
        template:'<i>{{color}}</i>',




        link: function(scope, el, attr){
            console.log("print attributes value: " + attr.color );

            scope.color=attr.color;

        }

    }

});
```

So far, I'm using ng-repeat in index.html to create a "test" element for each object contained in the rainbow list. This in turn displays the value "color". This works fine. However, I have added a further ng-click directive so that each time an element is clicked the value of its 'color' property becomes 'changed.'.

This is reflected in the list, however, not within the directive 'test'.

I'm not sure why this is though. I was under the impression that `<test color="{{el.color}}"` would have updated the parameter color in the directive when this was changed?

Any advice?

Dario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pandaApp = angular.module("pandaApp",[]);

pandaApp.controller('pandaController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


    $scope.rainbow = [

        {color:"red"},
        {color:"orange"},
        {color:"yellow"},
        {color:"blue"}

    ];

    $scope.updateColor = function(el) {

        el.color="changed";
        console.log("Changed")
    }

}]);

pandaApp.directive("test", function() {

    return {

        restrict:'E',
        template:'<i>{{color}}</i>',
        scope:{color:"@"},
        link: function(scope, el, attr){
            console.log("print attributes value: " + scope.color );
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attribute is a string and it's not going to update. Instead you need two-way binding from the scope into directive isolated scope:

```
pandaApp.directive("test", function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:'<i>{{color}}</i>',
        scope: {
            color: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {

        }
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ksC4XjlkP2XDpedTDuEZ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @dfsq, I also found that passing the whole object (<test color="{{el}}") and the changing my directive to emplate:'<i>{{el.color}}</i>', also works? (Ie: If that particular object is changed outside the directive the changes are reflected within.) Is that bad practice or am I fine to go with it?

Comment: You should not do it. The only reason why it works is that because in this case directive doesn't have isolated scope so it takes data from outside, where it happens to be object `el` (because of `ng-repeat="el in rainbow"`). If you change it to say `ng-repeat="element in rainbow"` you would also need to change template in directive to `'<i>{{element.color}}</i>'`. So this is the idea of isolated scope: not to depend on outer scope changes, you just pass data into directive and it knows only about its own internals but not outside world.

Comment: Check the demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/oP02vuFFUhOQaVOL6AwX?p=preview. Play with it and see how it works.